# WPF/ MVVM : Value of Textbox is not updating with selected file path but if go to next page and come back it is showing the value

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm asking user to provided file path for something. The problem is, it is not setting the value in text box with selected file path at first. but if I go to next page and comeback, it is showing the value in textbox.

xaml code:

```xml
<TextBox Grid.Row="5"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Margin="10 10 0 10"
         Style="{StaticResource Advanced}"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="CertPath" 
                 Mode="TwoWay" 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <advancedConfigurationPage:CertpathValidation 
                    ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<Button Grid.Row="5"
        Grid.Column="3"
        Margin="0 10 0 10"
        Style="{StaticResource Advanced}"
        Command="{Binding CertificatePathBrowseCommand}"
        Content="Browse"/>
```

and viewModel is:

```cs
this.CertificatePathBrowseCommand = new SimpleCommand(_ =>
{
    var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    this.CertPath =  openFileDialog.FileName;
}, _ => true);
```

CertPath property:

```cs
public string CertPath
{
    get => _certPath;    
    set
    {
        _certPath = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(CertPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the CertPath property?

Comment: sorry, edited the question. CertPath property is inside CertificatePathBrowseCommand.

Comment: You still don't show the code of the CertPath property. Is it possible that OnPropertyChanged is not called when setting the property?

Comment: It is called while setting the property. Please check the edited  post.

Comment: I don't know how your OnPropertyChanged is implemented, but shouldn't it be `OnPropertyChanged("CertPath")` or better `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CertPath))`? In the current implementation, it notifies about a property named like the path.

Comment: @user2727133 is right. You're notiying that some property have changed. You have to pass the name of that property as a string.

Comment: @user2727133 Thanku so much for the help. I'm new in MVVM and setting these properties. I spend lot of time to figure out this but could not do.
It works now.

Answer (score -1):

The PropertyChanged event in the parameters must pass the name of the property, not the value!

Additionally: According to the contract of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, the PropertyChanged event should be called when the value changes, not any value assignment.

Quoting from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0): "Notifies clients that a property value has **changed**".

```cs
public string CertPath
{
    get => _certPath;    
    set
    {

        if (Equals(_certPath, value))
            return;

        _certPath = value;

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CertPath));
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Additionally: According to the contract of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, the PropertyChanged event should be called when the value changes, not any value assignment."_ This is totally wrong. The contract requires you to implement the ProeprtyChanged event. The pattern requires you to raise this event on the binding source to allow to update the binding target on property changes. The logic or the condition that determines _what_ you actually consider a property change is up to the implementor and not defined by any contract or pattern.

Comment: Anyway, it's good practice to filter values, where the old value and the new value are the same, to improve performance.

Comment: Quoting from the documentation: "Notifies clients that a property value has **changed**".
Pay attention on CHANGED, but not ASSIGNED.

Comment: It's up to the interface implementor to decide when and where he raises the event. The implementor also decides what's equality and whether to check for reference equality or value equality. Using `Equals` will not always do what you expect. The definition of a change is not part of a "contract". A contract in software engineering means you have a caller/consumer that relies to operate on a defined object. Violating such a contract means the caller/consumer can't operate successfully. We implement contracts by introducing interfaces to provide compiler support in order to enforce a contract.

Comment: The data binding engine is so flexible, it even makes implementing INotifyPropertyChanged optional, means it doesn't even rely on the presence of a PropertyChanged event. As I said before, neither the condition of a change nor implementing a condition to decide when you raise PropertyChanged in general, is part of any contract. If you decide that each assignment should be treated as a change, so will it be. In addition, an interface is not able to force a specific implementation or logic. That's beyond the power of interafces.

Comment: Do not confuse working with a property through ONLY bindings and property change notification without using bindings.
Bindings to work with a property (reading and writing a value) use reflection: PropertyDescriptor, PropertyInfo, DependencyProperty, and DynamicPropertyAccessor.
For this reason, one binding "sees" changes made by another binding without using INPC.

Comment: But if you change the property value without using reflection (that is, directly in Sharp's code), then the bindings without raising PropertyChanged will  «notsee» this change.
If you understand Russian, read my two articles on this: https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2650880.html and https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2708685.html .
If you don't understand and you need additional explanations, then open a new topic here and in it I will give you detailed explanations with demo codes.

Comment: If the "consumer" of the class decides that for some purpose he needs to know the number of changes to the property value and he relies on the implementation of INPC according to the documentation, and will simply count the number of calls to PropertyChanged, then the creation of this event for any assignment of the value may lead to incorrect work consumer.
The same can happen if the consumer generates some additional objects when the value changes.

Comment: I agree with you that Equals is not a one-size-fits-all approach.
What is a "change" is finally decided by the author of the code.
But Equals, with rare exceptions, provides the functionality you need for most tasks.

Comment: Changing the value of a property using reflection doesn't make any sense in this context. WPF uses reflection to inspect the binding source, if the binding source does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Maybe this is what you mean. So implementing this interface is not a requirement in order to establish a binding. You can totally circumvent this interface and get a working two way binding. Simply implement an event that is named like the property and raise it. E.g. for `MyProperty` you would implement a `MyPropertyChanged` event. You can try it.

Comment: You can't and shouldn't rely on the assumption that the PropertyChanged event source has implemented a certain pattern. The consumer should always check for the required condition by itself. In your example, the consumer of PropertyChanged must check the new value against the old value in order to determine if the counter should be incremented. Again, a interface can never force a certain implementation. Since C#8 it can of course provide a default implementation, which can be overriden anytime by the implementor. What you are referring to is a pattern.

Comment: But the WPF binding engine does not rely on any pattern which describes how a property set method is implemented. The engine only looks for the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the binding source in order to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event. That's what the contract INotifyPropertyChanged is all about - guarantee the presence of the PropertyChanged event. The engine doesn't care how a property is implemented. You are even free to raise the PropertyChanged event outside the property set method only.

Comment: I use WPF professionally for years. I'm pretty sure I don't need any explanaition of such basics. But thank you for your offer ;)

Comment: I know Binding can use MyPropertyChanged.
These events are more common in forms, but WPF can use them too.
Similarly, for collections, you can use IBindingList instead of INotifyPropertyChanged.
But the speech, in this case, is only about the INPC interface.
As I understand it, Binding does not subscribe to PropertyChanged, but to PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged (...).
In one of the topics (the link to which I gave earlier), I showed a demo code when there are no events in the class and the property change notification occurs automatically when using PropertyDescriptor.SetValue (...).

Comment: And bindings keep track of such changes perfectly.
There is also an example that implements the PropertyChanged event but does not inherit from INPC.
And in such a case, Binding does not notice the property change, even if it raises an event.
For the same reason (that is, because there is no direct subscription to PropertyChanged), it doesn't matter on which thread this event occurs.
Direct subscription is used for the CanExecuteChanged and CollectionChanged events.
And because of this, these events have to be raised on the UI thread.

Comment: PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged (or the ValueChanged event to be more precise) is used when the binding source _does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged_. Otherwise there _is_ a direct subscription. That's what the interface is for. It only defines a single member - the PropertyChanged event. If your class or CLR object does not implement the interface, then the engine will not look for the PropertyChanged event and therfore will not listen to it. Instead it will use reflection to obtain the PropertyDescriptor.

Comment: Your observations are correct, but your interpretations or explanaitions are wrong. The best way in terms of performance is to use a DependencyProeperty as binding source, as this won't involve any reflection at all. Then comes INotifyPropertyChanged, as listening to the PropertyChanged event does not involve any static references, like ValueChanged does. Using this third method (the method you have described) performs the worse.

Comment: This is because the engine relies heavily on reflection and in addition creates a static reference to the observed object (the binding source), This static reference will create a memory leak too. This is because static references won't be collected by the garbage collector and are kept alive for the lifetime of the application. This means _each!_ binding to a source that is not a dependency property and does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged creates a memory leak where the source's lifetime is expected to end before the application terminates.

Comment: If you want to learn how binding works you can start with this article [Microsoft Docs: How Data Binding References are Resolved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#how-data-binding-references-are-resolved).

Comment: And the reason why it doesn't matter on which thread the PropertyChanged event is raised, is that the engine will always marshal the event to the UI thread. It does that by design. This makes sense as a data binding is usually established with a UI element as target, therefore the PropertyChanged handler is requiered to execute on the same UI thread. Again, your observations are absolutely correct, but your explanation is not.

Comment: Also CollectionChanged  is not marshalled by the binding engine, as this event is not primarily intended to be used with data binding. Therefore the owner of the collection is responsible to marshal the CollectionChanged event to the UI thread when the collection is used with data binding. Or alternatively use [BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=net-5.0#remarks) method. This way you don't have to take care about on which thread the collection is modified.

Comment: Your answers prompted me to dig deeper with the source codes.
And you were right, for types with INPC implementation - "direct" subscription is used.
But despite this subscription, getting the value of the source property still occurs through reflection: the `internal object GetValue (object item, int level)` method - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/PropertyPathWorker.cs,232

Comment: As for the "contract" to change the value of a property, not any assignment to it.
Then I agree with you that you cannot completely rely on this.
But this is rather because the INPC implementation may not fully conform to the contract of that interface.
And, whenever possible, it is better to guard against possible incorrect implementations.
But it does not follow from this that the contract does not specify to create an event only when the property value changes.

Comment: Absolutely correct. The engine needs reflection to get the value of the source property, because it only gets the name of the property via `PropertyChangedEventArgs`. That's the only information the engine has about the binding source (beside that it exposes the `PropertyChanged` event). To get the value without reflection, the engine (framework) would have to know the concrete source object, the INPC implementation, (we are talking of plain CLR properties at this point), which is impossible. This is the only little reflection that is required, that's correct when implementing INPC.

Comment: As you can read in the previous provided link aboiut resolving bindings, you can know that dependency properties are the only solution that uses zero reflection and therefore offers the best performance (by far). This is because every dependency property is registered and stored in a lookup table. Remember that you register a dependency property using the static `DependencyProperty.Register` method. The string parameter is used to store the refence in the nternal lookup table (that's why it must be unique).

Comment: Now, when the dp property changes, the binding engine can use the property name to lookup the property and use it as the parameter for `DependencyObject.GetValue` . That's clever but simple. The contract here is that the owner of the dependency property must: 1) register the property with a unique name (string value) 2) must extend `DependencyObject` (to provide the `GetValue` member).

Comment: Regarding your last comment: it is not the responsibility of a framework to dictate how you must implement something (otherwise there would be an abstract class introduced. A framework always requests a contract and leaves the behavior (which makes the application) to the implementor. From a framework point of vieew there are no incorrect implementations.

Comment: If you implement the proper interface, but your implementation does garbage, then it's your fault. By giving you all this freedom you are able to create applications that the developer aof a framework was never dreaming of. That's how frameworks work: they call your code by accessinng it via the interface or abstract class implementations.